# Shortest path in graph by flipping binary colored nodes to one color

Tags: shortest-path, graph-traversal, colorings

Given a graph consists of two-colored nodes(e.g. white and black) and a starting node, and every time you visit a node, its color is switched(from black to white, or, white to black), how to find the minimum path such that all nodes are converted to black (or white, since it is equivalent)?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Why should this problem be considered interesting (i.e., why are you trying to solve this and not some other problem)?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is $NP$-complete, there is a quite simple reduction from Hamiltonian Path. Therefore, there's (likely) no way to solve this problem efficiently in general, so the solution method will need to be tailored to the inputs you are interested in solving (brute force for small instances, heuristic methods for large instances, specialized methods for instances with special structure,...).

Comment: Would you mind expanding on the reduction from the Hamiltonian Path problem?

Comment: @RcnSc Construct an instance where all the nodes initially have the same color, and go from there.

Comment: Perhaps I am overlooking something here, but I am not immediately convinced. There are graphs that have no Hamiltonian path, but do have a path where every vertex is visited an odd number of times?

Comment: @HendrikJan The question asks for the shortest path.